# How to submit a form using jQuery in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to submit a form like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="$('#form1').submit();" value="Create" />
```

but the [ASP.NET MVC 2 Model Validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) doesn't work.

Comment: In which way does it not work? Have you tried using AJAX instead? What exactly do you try to accomplish with the line above? jQuery's .submit() will NOT submit the form data. Also, you should register a callback to see the result. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Client or server side validation doesn't work?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you are using jQuery for this at all? Why don't you use a simple submit button? You can still register callbacks using `ajaxForm`.

Comment: The client validation doesn't work.
My page is a little complex, contains several forms. And our client demand the submit button should place at the bottom of page.
So I have to do like before, a submit button outside it's form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try simulating a click on the actual submit button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="$('#form1 input:submit').click();" value="Create" />
```

Comment: This way is good! Thanks!
But I have to put a hidden submit button in my form.
I wait to see if there is a better way.

Comment: It is semantically more correct to submit forms with submit or image buttons.